# How to group elements in a dataframe/list only if their sums are equal?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I want to combine elements if their bought and sold quantities are the same for a date and left out the remaining ones as shown in the below example.

Data Set:

```
 1/1/09 bought 100 AAPL
 1/1/09 sold 100 AAPL
 1/1/09 bought 35 AAPL
 1/1/09 sold 35 AAPL
 1/1/09 bought 105 AAPL
```

I want the resulting Data Frame to be:

```
1/1/09 bought 135 AAPL
1/1/09 sold 135 AAPL
1/1/09 bought 105 AAPL
```

Answer (score 0):

Just groupby and sum:

```
my_var = ['bought','sold','bought','sold','bought']
dollar = [100,100,35,35,105]
date = ['2009-01-01','2009-01-01','2009-01-01','2009-01-01','2009-01-01']
sku = ['AAPL','AAPL','AAPL','AAPL','AAPL']

df = pd.DataFrame({'status':pd.Series(my_var),'dollars':pd.Series(dollar),'date':pd.Series(date),'SKU':pd.Series(sku)})

df.groupby(['SKU','status','date'],as_index = False)['dollars'].sum()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But the problem is all these quantities are on the same date.

Comment: Edited the question with a more precise example. Thank you

Comment: Is there a reason why 'bought' isn't being summed up as 1 variable?

Comment: Yes, I only want to combine if 'Sold' (quantity)== 'Bought' (quantity). Basically its some inventory data.

Comment: is "XXX" the SKU number?

Comment: Its the Item name similar to the SKU number.

Comment: Actually, all the ones mentioned above are of the same SKU number.

Comment: Okay, i've edited my answer, if you need to compare the bought and sold status's of each SKU unit, you can pivot the dataframe by the SKU unit and then apply a filter